# UIScreen.main.bounds.width returning nil in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, size, screen, uiscreen

In my project, I got messed up with two versions of app. I propably copied the project file and it created a problem. This line

```
myLogo.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

shows, that `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` returns nil. How is that even possible?

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What could be the reason and how can I repair it?

I'm working on the latest Xcode and writing in Swift 3.

Comment: Uhhh that shouldn't be possible. Nothing from `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` is optional. Are you sure that it's not your `myLogo` that's returning `nil`? Is `myLogo` optional?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var myLogo: UIImageView!

Comment: That's optional - I would bet that's what it is. Do yourself a favor and check. When it crashes, inside the debugger type in `po myLogo` and see if it returns `nil`

Comment: It's technically a force-unwrapped optional, but it can still return `nil`

Comment: @Norman makes a good point below too, the `width` of a frame is read-only. You'll need to set the entire frame, but that still won't fix your `nil` problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure `myLogo` is connected to your storyboard (the little dot to the left of `myLogo`'s declaration should be dark). Then set it's frame's width property like this:

```
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let r = myLogo.frame
    myLogo.frame = CGRect(x: r.origin.x, y: r.origin.y, width: width, height: r.height)
```

This would probably be better to do in Interface Builder with auto-layout so `myLogo`'s width is constrained to the device's width.

Here's a [useful extension](https://gist.github.com/nbasham/84ce5b1fdec949115999b738217bde65) that lets you adjust individual properties of a UIView's frame e.g.

```
myLogo.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

Comment: After copying these files, the connection got lost. I just had to connect it to the storyboard. Thanks for your help, guys!